# Sort dataframe by asc and desc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has two columns, let's call A and B I want to sort A desc and B asc.

In order words, I want a list of elements which has a minor value in columns A and a greater value in column B

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass 0 (false), 1 (true) to the ascending attribute in sort_values

```
df.sort_values(['cola','colb'], ascending=[0,1]
```